# How to search a query between 2 time in php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I need to search a row between 2 times in one day 
for example

current time is **13.30 O'clock**

The first time is **13.00 O'clock**

The second time is **14.00 O'clock**

If the current time is between the first time and the second time, return true, else return false

i make some code like this :

`$today = date("Y-m-d");`

`$this->db->query("select date, in, out from absent where date='$today' and id_user='120'")->result();
    /*
        the result is 3 rows 
        2019-3-7, 13:00, 14:00 
        2019-3-7, 09.00, 12.00
        2019-3-7, 15:00, 17:00
    */`

I just need one row  which the current time is between the first and second time

Comment: jquery and JS has nothing to do with the query added sql to tags

Comment: show your so far query

Comment: Please elaborate on this part of your question: "and then convert the first time and second time to strtotime, but how if the result of the query is 2 rows?", 

Right now it's not fully clear what you did, what you are expecting to see, and what you saw instead.

Comment: sorry i have edited some detail i need

Comment: _“but how if the result of the query is 2 rows?”_ - same “how” as always, when you have to perform any task more than once: In a _loop_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (if you have a single date time field):

```
$firstTime = (new DateTime)->format('H:i:s');
$secondTime = (new DateTime)->modify('+1 hours +2 minutes +3 seconds')->format('H:i:s');


$this->db->query("SELECT `date`, in, out FROM absent WHERE TIME(`date`) >= '$firstTime' AND TIME(`date`) <= '$secondTime' AND id_user='120'");
```

Date is a reserved word in MySQL so you have to escape it. You can do this for any part of a datetime field, `MONTH()`, `DAY()`, `YEAR()`, `TIME()`, `HOUR()`  etc..

Then you just match your date format in this case just the time `H:i:s` and a bit of logic.

It's not clear but you may need something like this as it looks like you have a date field and two fields with Hour and Minutes?

```
$today = new DateTime;

$date = $today->format('Y-m-d');
$in = $today->format('H:i');
$out = $today->modify('+2 hours')->format('H:i');


$this->db->query("SELECT `date`, in, out FROM absent WHERE `date` = '$date' AND in >= '$in' AND out <= '$out' AND id_user='120'");
```

Personally in this case I would make in and out be full datetime fields, then you can use the date functions like above, and you can eliminate one column, and handle in and out values that bridge a date.

Comment: Sure! - glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
$this->db->select('date, in, out');
$this->db->from('absent');
$this->db->where('date', $today);
$this->db->where('user_id', '120');
$this->db->where('in >='. $currentTime);
$this->db->where('out <='. $currentTime);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

First, convert all three times into `strtotime()`

Second, `result()` will always give you more than one row if it will retrieve. Use `row()` to get only one record

```
$current = strtotime('time-one');
$first_time = strtotime('time-two');
$second_time = strtotime('time-three');
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

**Query**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('date', $date);
$this->db->where('user_id', '120');
$this->db->where('time >='. $first_time);
$this->db->where('time <='. $second_time);
return $this->db->get()->row();
```

Comment: sorry i'm not explain my problem clearly, i have edited it. the first and second time in database column is time format like 14:00 or 10:00 if i change it to strtotime(), can i search it in query ?

Comment: @Rif yes why not

Comment: i tried it, it won't give me a row i want, if i just force it to just take one row, how can i know that row is a row from the current time or not ?

Comment: @Rif what you mean by this "  how can i know that row is a row " ?